# can bash show one array item id and value using `declare -p`?

Tags: bash, array

```
$ str="a'\"b"
$ declare -p str
declare -- str="a'\"b" # see " was escaped, possibly other chars will too
$ astr=("$str" "c")
$ declare -p astr
declare -ax astr='([0]="a'\''\"b" [1]="c")'
```

so, is there some way to do something like `declare -p astr[0]` and retrieve something like this: `declare -- astr[0]="a'\"b"` ?

I could use `sed` or something else, but I would like to know if bash allow accessing astr[n] thru `declare -p` in some way I couldn't guess yet?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are just looking for a way of displaying the data with escaped special characters, then the `%q` format string of `printf` in `bash` would do that for you:

```
printf '%q\n' "${astr[0]}"
```

To replicate the `declare -p`-like output that you suggest:

```
printf 'declare -- astr[0]="%q"\n' "${astr[0]}"
```

This is from the `bash` manual, regarding the `%q` format string of `printf`:

> `%q`
>
> causes `printf` to output the corresponding argument in a format that can be  reused
>          as shell input.

Comment: it is a lot simpler than using sed and does the same thing I was looking for, thx!

Answer (score 0):

With bash v4.4 you can use the `@A` parameter expansion operator to get similar results, but not effectively for a single array element:

> **A**
>
> > The expansion is a string in the form of an assignment statement or declare command that, if evaluated, will recreate parameter with its attributes and value.

```
$ str="a'\"b"
$ astr=("$str" "c")
$ echo ${astr[0]@A}
declare -a astr='a'\''"b'
$ echo ${astr[@]@A}
declare -a astr=([0]="a'\"b" [1]="c")
```

Or similar to the `%q` printf format you can use the `@Q` operator:

```
$ echo ${astr[0]@Q}
'a'\''"b'
$ echo "declare -- astr[0]=${astr[0]@Q}"
declare -- astr[0]='a'\''"b'
```

Comment: a new feature, interesting! mine is v4.3.48, I am almost installing 18.04 (16.04 here), I will check then :)